# How to make Firebase database rules so that you cannot query root /

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

My database looks something like this:

[image: database]

How can I make Firebse realtime database rules so that I can query `classes/18043249279` (or any other folder inside classes/), but not `classes` as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify a certain path with Firebase Realtime Database. For information as to how the rules work for Realtime Database, please click [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax)

I highly recommend that you use Cloud Firestore by Firebase, which would allow you specify what files certain users can view in a collection. More information for Cloud Firestore can be found here [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview)